# Checking multiple occurrences and manipulating them using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a requirement in which I need to check all four values of both occurrences in one condition and it is not given that `hey1` and `hello1` will come in one occurrence and `hey2` and `hello2` in the other. 
I mean it is not guaranteed that `hey1` or `hey2` come in as first or second; the same applies for `hello1` and `hello2`.

I am using the below code which gives me the output `<output>ININ</output>`, but I need it as `<output>IN</output>`.

I am trying this POC and I have a sample XML below:

```
<q>
        <a>
          <b>hey1</b>
          <c>hello1</c>
        </a>
        <a>
          <b>hey2</b>
          <c>hello2</c>
        </a>
</q>
```

Kindly provide me a solution which checks all four conditions and in which one `if/when` condition used for each `<a>` will occur twice or multiple times.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" version="1.0" method="xml" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="a" select="/q/a"/>
          <output>
                <xsl:for-each select="$a">
                    <xsl:if test="$a/b='hey1' and $a/c= 'hello1' and $a/b='hey2' and $a/c= 'hello2'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'IN'"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </output>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I hope that I my question is clear enough to answer it.
Thank you for any advice.

Comment: "*I need to check the all four values*" Each`a` has only two.

Comment: yes two values in both <a> occurrences, so it is four right.

Comment: But you are testing for each `a` individually.  Will there be always exactly two occurrences of 'a', each having exactly one `b` and one `c`?

Comment: yes there will be two occurrences of <a> always each having exactly one b and one c.

Comment: I have rolled back your question to its previous form. Please post your new question separately, as it is completely different from this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:template match="q">
    <xsl:if test="a[b='hey1' and c='hello1'] and a[b='hey2' and c='hello2'] ">
        <xsl:text>IN</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

This will return `"IN"` for both:

```
<q>
   <a>
      <b>hey1</b>
      <c>hello1</c>
   </a>
   <a>
      <b>hey2</b>
      <c>hello2</c>
   </a>
</q>
```

and:

```
<q>
   <a>
      <b>hey2</b>
      <c>hello2</c>
   </a>
   <a>
      <b>hey1</b>
      <c>hello1</c>
   </a>
</q>
```

but not for:

```
<q>
   <a>
      <b>hey1</b>
      <c>hello2</c>
   </a>
   <a>
      <b>hey2</b>
      <c>hello1</c>
   </a>
</q>
```

Comment: thanks for that, so what we have to do for the third xml to work?

Comment: can you pls give a solution with for-each ??

Comment: @AK.DataPower For each what?

Comment: instead of template match , can we do it with <xsl:for-each> ??

Comment: I have updated the question with actual code and input xml, can I get get help on this pls

Comment: Please post this as a new question. I have already rolled this question back to what it was before.